# How to allocate a constant array to RAM other than LUTs

Tags: fpga, verilog, ram

I'm still pretty new to hardware design.

Now I need to store a number of constants and then use them as indexes.

My first idea is to declare registers, `reg [5:0] index[100000:0];`, for them, but I know it would be a vast waste of resource if they were allocated to LUTs by synthesis.

My question is: what is the correct way to store and initialize a number of constants in RAM (or somewhere cheaper) other than LUTs?

Thanks for any guideline.

Comment: Generally the tools for the device you’re targeting have means of generating a block ram which gets included into your project.

Comment: oh thanks @Kartman, do you imply that we cannot make a device-independent and IP-core-free code to achieve that goal, in general?

Comment: @xcwang Not if you want to use hardware specific features.

Comment: @xcwang If you are on FPGA, make use of block ram models in Verilog (refer to relevant tool synthesis guide). Normally the RTL model is portable across FPGAs with minimal/no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"reg" is just a data type in Verilog, it doesn't necessarily mean "register".  If you declare the array correctly and access it correctly, the tools can implement it on a block RAM.  Usually there is a recommended synthesis template, if you follow that it will work.  Generally for simple RAMs you can write portable code that all tools that don't completely suck will be able to deal with.

However, there are a number of things to watch out for, especially for someone coming from a software background.  First, the number of read and write ports that you request must actually be implementable in the hardware, otherwise the tools will not infer block RAM.  Usually every place you "dereference" the array in the HDL will imply a port, with some exceptions (for instance, an if block to switch between reading and writing on the same port based on a write enable signal).  Generally block RAM resources support two ports per RAM, with each port having its own address input and the ability to both read and write.  If you use more than two ports, it might still be possible for the synthesizer to infer the RAM through duplication.  For instance, one write-only port and N read-only ports should result in N copies of the RAM with all the write ports tied together.  You may have to split off the actual RAM read from where the value will end up being used, and I definitely recommend doing that for someone who is new to working with HDLs.  If multiple components need to access the RAM, then you will need to decide how best to handle it, depending on design requirements - maybe you just replicate the RAM (or see if the tools will replicate it for you), or maybe you need to implement explicit arbitration logic.

For initializing the RAM, most tools support doing this in an initial block.  You can directly put the values in the HDL, or you can use readmemh/readmemb to read them in from a separate text file.  Note that there is no way to "reset" the contents of a RAM aside from reloading the FPGA configuration, so if you add a "reset" input that reloads the initial contents, then the tool will infer flip flops instead of a RAM.  However, you can certainly write a state machine that can write some values into RAM after a reset; I have done this several times before to initialize RAMs with zeros.  If you need to initialize to a non-trivial pattern, then you may need to implement both a ROM and a RAM and write a state machine to copy the ROM contents to the RAM.